# vb.net: Try and catch error handling, reset values

Tags: vb.net, try-catch

while working on my project (converter) I came across a problem with "try and catch" error handling:

All values should be reseted, after inserting numbers which are out of range (0 - 1000).

I tried to use:

```
 txtAcre.Text = ""
 txtSqaMeter.Text = ""
 txtHectare.Text = ""
```

but then it won't display anything.

As you might notice I'm an absolutely beginner, so just keep you explanations simple :D

Thanks for your help!

Here's the full code

```
  Const Hectare_min = 0
    Const Hectare_max = 1000

    If rbHectare.Checked And IsNumeric(txtHectare.Text) Then
        Try
            dblHectare = CDbl(txtHectare.Text)
            If dblHectare <= Hectare_min Or dblHectare >= Hectare_max Then
                Throw New Exception
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Please choose a value between 0 and 1000")
        End Try
    End If
    txtAcre.Text = ""
    txtSqaMeter.Text = ""
    txtHectare.Text = ""
```

Comment: You shouldn't be throwing an exception unless the behaviour being exhibited is absolutely exceptional. Just move the textbox text assigments into the `If` statement.

Comment: Exceptions are meant to be used like that ... instead, use a simple `If` - nowadays you can even use it with [three parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985(v=vs.140).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use exceptions for flow control.  They can be costly in terms of performance.  Since you are using `Double`, then just use `Double.TryParse`:

```
Const Hectare_min = 0
Const Hectare_max = 1000

If rbHectare.Checked And IsNumeric(txtHectare.Text) Then
    If Double.TryParse(txtHectare.Text, dblHectare) Then
        If dblHectare <= Hectare_min Or dblHectare >= Hectare_max Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please choose a value between 0 and 1000")
            txtAcre.Text = ""
            txtSqaMeter.Text = ""
            txtHectare.Text = ""   
            Return  'Or whatever is appropriate for your application             
        End If

        'If the code reaches here, then the user has entered a valid value           

    Else
        MessageBox.Show("The value you entered is not a valid.")
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If rbHectare.Checked And IsNumeric(txtHectare.Text) Then
    Try
        dblHectare = CDbl(txtHectare.Text)
        If dblHectare <= Hectare_min Or dblHectare >= Hectare_max Then

                 txtAcre.Text = "0.0"
                  txtSqaMeter.Text = "0.0"
                txtHectare.Text = "0.0"
              Throw New Exception
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Please choose a value between 0 and 1000")
    End Try
End If
```

You could try changing the text box text to 0.0 rather than a null string.